# how does fill-rule="evenodd" work on a star SVG

Tags: svg

I saw the following svg shape when i was trying to understand `fill-rule` in SVG

```
<div class="contain-demo">
  <svg width="250px" height="250px" viewBox="0 0 250 250">
    <desc>Yellow star with intersecting paths to demonstrate evenodd value.</desc>
    <polygon fill="#F9F38C" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="#E5D50C" stroke-width="5" stroke-linejoin="round" points="47.773,241.534 123.868,8.466 200.427,241.534 7.784,98.208 242.216,98.208 " />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Please note the following:

- The SVG has just one path.
- The SVG has intersecting points.
- if i change **fill-rule="nonzero"** the entire SVG get the fill.
- Currently with **fill-rule="evenodd"** applied the SVG's central area does't get the fill.

Why is it that with `fill-rule="evenodd"` the central portion of the star SVG is not filled ?

I did read the spec for `fill-rule="evenodd"`

> This value determines the "insideness" of a point in the shape by
>   drawing a ray from that point to infinity in any direction and
>   counting the number of path segments from the given shape that the ray
>   crosses. If this number is odd, the point is inside; if even, the
>   point is outside.

But i still don't understand why when i apply `fill-rule="evenodd"`, the middle of the star is not filled. Can somebody please explain this ?

Comment: Your comment makes sense now !

Comment: Linking the spec for fill-rule: https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/painting.html#FillRuleProperty

Answer (score 59, accepted):

This is how the mechanism works. Pick a point in the center, draw lines to infinity in any direction - they always cross an even number of path segments -which means that they are "outside" and their areas don't get filled.

Pick a point in the filled triangles - if you draw lines to infinity in any direction - they always cross an odd number of path segments and thus, they are "inside" and their area should be filled.

[image: fill-rule even odd]