# Modify the svg path to remove fill portion

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have an svg path as below

```
M 1.6667 0.6666 H 20.3333 C 21.0697 0.6666 21.6667 1.2636 21.6667 2 V 18 C 21.6667 18.7363 21.0697 19.3333 20.3333 19.3333 H 1.6667 C 0.9303 19.3333 0.3333 18.7363 0.3333 18 V 2 C 0.3333 1.2636 0.9303 0.6666 1.6667 0.6666 Z M 20.3333 2 H 2 V 4.8 H 20.3333 V 2 Z M 1.6667 18 V 5.8666 H 20.3333 V 18 H1.6667 Z M 9 2.6666 H 7.6667 V 4 H 9 V 2.6666 Z M 5 2.6666 H 6.3333 V 4 H 5 V 2.6666 Z M 3.6667 2.6666 H 2.3333 V 4 H 3.6667 V 2.6666 Z
```

when I enter this path on https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/, I get the generated shape. Now, how do I modify this path to make the inner rectangular section as not-filled(or hollow). I am referring to the largest rectangle inside the main shape.

[image]

Comment: I edited the SVG in Figma, and to remove the fill in the middle rectangle it added these two properties `fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd"`. I don't know if that helps.

Comment: This is how fill-rule evenodd works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46017839/how-does-fill-rule-evenodd-work-on-a-star-svg/46145333

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just delete the top line and drag the bottom line up.

```
M 1.6667 0.6666 H 20.3333 C 21.0697 0.6666 21.6667 1.2636 21.6667 2 V 18 C 21.6667 18.7363 21.0697 19.3333 20.3333 19.3333 H 1.6667 C 0.9303 19.3333 0.3333 18.7363 0.3333 18 V 2 C 0.3333 1.2636 0.9303 0.6666 1.6667 0.6666 Z M 20.3333 2 H 2 V 4.8 H 20.3333 V 2 Z M 1.6667 18 H 20 V 6 H 1.6667 Z M 9 2.6666 H 7.6667 V 4 H 9 V 2.6666 Z M 5 2.6666 H 6.3333 V 4 H 5 V 2.6666 Z M 3.6667 2.6666 H 2.3333 V 4 H 3.6667 V 2.6666 Z
```

Your square's sides are swapped. You can just change it, but deleting and recreating the square remove the extra points you have there.